# Обойти блокировку telegram для создания бота. А может быть дело совсем не в блокировке?

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Прокси рабочий, проверял.

https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBotsExample/issues/20
Здесь описано другое решение этого вопроса, которое мне не помогло.

```
'''

public class Main {

private static String BOT_NAME = "-------";
private static String BOT_TOKEN = "--------" ;

private static String PROXY_HOST = "137.74.188.56" ;
private static Integer PROXY_PORT = 1080 ;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        ApiContextInitializer.init();

        // Create the TelegramBotsApi object to register your bots
        TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();


        DefaultBotOptions botOptions = ApiContext.getInstance(DefaultBotOptions.class);

        botOptions.setProxyHost(PROXY_HOST);
        botOptions.setProxyPort(PROXY_PORT);

        botOptions.setProxyType(DefaultBotOptions.ProxyType.SOCKS5);


        Bot bot = new Bot(BOT_TOKEN, BOT_NAME , botOptions);

        botsApi.registerBot(bot);

    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }




'''
```

[image: ооочень много ошибок]

Comment: в чём вопрос-то?

Comment: Как запустить бота, чтобы он работал и подключался к серверам телеги?. Что не правильно в коде или может какими-то другими способами подключиться?

Comment: api.telegram.org заблокирован, попробуйте с прокси, должно заработать.

Comment: В том-то и дело , что это уже с прокси

Comment: Эта проблема тянется уже несколько недель. Пускаю бота через сокс прокси тора. Переодически api.telegram.org не резолвиться. Ркн что ли... Переодически пробуйте запустить или  попробуйте dns по типу 8.8.8.8

Comment: Купил VDS сервер за 2 рубля в день, буду пробовать через него. 
Через ТОР тоже никакого результата...

Answer (score -1):

Сталкивался с подобными проблемами, всё решилось после того, когда приобрёл VDS на Европейских серверах, развернул на нём socks5 и пускал бота через него.